# Kwic functions returns "kwic object with 0 rows" even though it should not

Tags: r

I have a problem reading data from a text file. My text file has a similar format to this:

```
A.1 Hello
A.2 Hi
A.3 Hey
```

I had extracted these sections from another file, into this file.
The original had the same format as this:

```
A.1 Hello
Blah blah blah. Other random sentence.
A.2 Hi
Blah blah blah blah. Other random sentences.
A.3 Hey
Blah blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence.
```

I wanted to perform the kiwc function:

```
kwic( original,phrase(sections), window =20, valuetype="fixed", 
case_insensitive = TRUE)
```

But this returns:

```
kwic object with 0 rows
```

I do not understand why this is. Quanteda is the package used for kwic. Original stands for the original text file and sections is the file that contains the sections I extracted.

Comment: Please show the package used for kwic

Comment: Add some extra info to your question, preferably based on one the datasets in quanteda. As it stands now it is difficult to see what the issue is.

Comment: Well, quanteda is the package used for kwic. And, original stands for the original text file and sections is the file that contains the sections I extracted. This kwic function should return twenty words before and after the sections in the original file.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. Are you sure that your sections are exactly as written in your original? Same case etc? You might have end-of-line delimiters before and after your sections. a dput of original would help to see what is going on. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: I added how the original looks like.